# Are these standard connectors i.e have a well defined I/O strcuture?

Tags: connector, pin-headers

I have found an FPGA board that contains this in description:

Arduino™ compatible expansion headers
MikroBUS™ compatible expansion headers
PMOD™ compatible expansion connector

Are these standard pinouts? Is their electrical and mechanical layout covered by a standard from ANSI or IEEE?

If these have a fixed pinout, where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they are standard and documented and very common. But they are not official standards, for example the Arduino connector pinout is simply just "all pins of MCU you ever need directly connected to two standard pin headers without much thought".

Comment: So I wonder what it could mean to have all these connectors on an FPGA board, they are all intended to be used with Microcontroller boards is it not?

Comment: It simply means the FPGA board has specific connectors for directly plugging in Arduino "shields" and PMOD modules, so you don't need any custom wiring.